# R - Names Function not working in R Commander (Rcmdr)

Tags: r, names

I'm new to R.  I assigned a variable to days of the week along with values for each day.  Then I tried to set the values (in numeric) to the days of the week variable but received the following error:

> "[4] ERROR: no applicable method for 'Names<-' applied to an object of
>   class "c('double', 'numeric')"

I believe I followed all the steps but I don't understand why when I use the `names(Poker_PL) <- Days_Name` command it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: There is no "Names" function. Try "names". Repeat 100 times: `R IS CASE SENSITIVE`

Comment: Nothing to do with Rcmdr. Closevote as a "typo"

Comment: Did it 99 times--- here is the 100th, "R IS CASE SENSITIVE".
This solved the problem (SQL bad habits) - thank you so much, very much appreciated.